# Pressing the power button to turn off screen is restarting the activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-camera

Here is what is happening. I have a simple camera application that takes a picture. I mostly copied the code from the Android Camera javadoc

1) I press the powerbutton. I see the following in my logs.

> I/ImageUploader(15724): OnPause
>
> I/ImageUploader(15724): Surface Preview Destroyed
>
> I/ImageUploader(15724): OnCreate
>
> I/ImageUploader(15724): OnResume
>
> I/ImageUploader(15724): OnPause

What i down understand is why is OnCreate being called after onPause?

Here is my OnPause code.

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Logger.i("OnPause");

    //turn off the screen
    if(previewLayout!=null){
        previewLayout.setKeepScreenOn(false);
    }

    //release the camera
    if(camera != null) {
        camera.stopPreview();
        //preview.setCamera(null);
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
        //preview.mHolder.addCallback(null);
        preview = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was simple. It was occurring because of configuration change. Just add it to your activity in your manifest.

```
<activity 
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize"
        android:name=".About"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
```